# Is the Croatian dialectism "regast" (full of cracks) related to Ancient Greek ῥαγή ("rhage", crack)?

Tags: etymology, ancient-greek

What do you guys here think, is the Croatian dialectism ["regast" ("full of cracks", in the Kaikavian diealect)](https://kajkavski.hr/rjecnik/?letter=r&page=207) or "regav" ("wrinkled", in the Donji Miholjac dialect) related to the Ancient Greek word "ῥαγή" ("rhage", "crack")?

Could, for example, both of them be borrowed from Illyrian? The change from 'a' to 'e' could be for the same reason the ancient name for the island of Brač, *Brattia*, was sometimes written as *Brettia*. Or why the modern name for Split, called *Spalathos* in antiquity, looks as if it was borrowed from *Speltos, with a change from 'a' to 'e'. Or why the modern name Bribir, from the ancient name *Varvaria*, looks as if it was borrowed from *Ververia, with a change from 'a' to 'e'.

Answer (score 2):

ῥαγή does not have a plausible etymology (Beekes thinks it is pre-Greek). Your suggestion is certainly worth considering.

Answer (score 1):

The northern areas of the Kajkavian region were part of the Kingdom of Hungary for centuries, and Donji Miholjac is still on the Croatian-Hungarian language border. Therefore I think both “regast” and “regav” are borrowings from the neighbouring Hungarian adjective “régi” /'re:gi/, the main meaning of which is ‘old’, but it can also mean ‘used, worn’ when applied to objects. If the object (e.g. a piece of wood) ages in such a way that cracks appear on it, the general meaning ‘old’ can evolve into the more specific meaning ‘cracked’. The faces of old people and the worn-out clothes can both be described as ‘wrinkled’.

It is common to add the adaptive suffix “-av” or “-ast” to Hungarian adjectives that have been borrowed into Croatian and Serbian (either at dialect or literary language level). Known examples from literature: “csonka” (broken, mangled, maimed) > “čonkav”, “sánta” (lame, limping) > “šantav”, “kedves” (dear, kind, gentle, lovely) > “kedvast”, “kurta” (short, brief) > “kurtast”.

In addition to the above, the fact that this “reg-” stem occurs with a variety of suffixes less typical in old adjectives does not support the idea that it is an old etymon going back to some kind of “Illyrian coexistence”. Furthermore, the borrowing of toponyms and (not wanderwort-like) apellatives is subject to different conditions. The borrowing of apellatives can only be justified if a set of similar developments can be identified. If the Illyrian connection is mentioned, the Albanian language cannot be excluded from the analysis. The Greek word “ῥαγή” is related to the Albanian noun “rregë” (fallow land). While this suggests that such a wanderwort may have existed in the Balkans, it also raises semantic problems and highlights the contradiction that the root word itself is not datable in BCMS and the supposed derivation is only found in the dialect furthest from Greek and Albanian.

P.S. Obviously, information on the quality of the “e” sound of the words “regast” and “regav” would not be useless in answering this question.